# Calcular cuantos años han pasado con una edad mayor a 60 en un alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta en las edades de usuarios. Tengo un alias edad y necesito otro alias donde me diga cuantos años han pasado despues 60 años en el alias edad.
Mi codigo es el siguiente.
Muchas gracias por la atencion.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, FechaNacimiento, 
       GETDATE()) AS Edad , 
       Apellidos, 
       Nombre, 
       FechaNacimiento
FROM Empleados
```

Comment: ¿Qué motor de bases de datos?

Comment: @Aprendiz estoy usando Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un case when, con la misma función DateDiff que tienes en el primer alias, y restarle los 60 años deseados.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Empleados 
(Id Int, Nombre Varchar(100), Apellidos Varchar(100),  FechaNacimiento Date)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Empleados (Id, Nombre, Apellidos, FechaNacimiento)
VALUES
(1,'Ana'    ,'Vargas','19700501'),
(2,'Bea'    ,'Pérez' ,'19620112'),
(3,'Carlos' ,'Solís' ,'19470324'),
(4,'Alina'  ,'Mejía' ,'19271231'),
(5,'Javier' ,'Ruiz'  ,'19990610'),
(6,'Isa'    ,'Otero' ,'20000530'),
(7,'Felipe' ,'Meana' ,'19730501');
GO

SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, FechaNacimiento, 
       GETDATE()) AS Edad , 
       Apellidos, 
       Nombre, 
       FechaNacimiento,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, FechaNacimiento, GETDATE()) > 60 
            THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, FechaNacimiento, GETDATE()) - 60 
            ELSE 0 END As Despues60
FROM dbo.Empleados 
GO
```

[image: Solución]